# Add to cart button not changing cart quantity

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a site with 5 separate `detail.html` pages generated with an if funtion and an array with items and item details.

I am trying to use an "add to cart" button on `product_details.html` page to change the quantity in the apropriate quantity field on the `order.html` page.

The add to cart button sets a cookie, but it does not change the value field on the `order.html` page.

**`details.html`**

```
//create add to cart button
document.write("<input type='button' href='order.html' value='Add to    Cart' onclick='setCookie(" + id + ")' />");

//set the cookie value
function setCookie(value)  {            
    document.cookie ="q" + value + "=1"; domain="/";
    window.location.href = 'order.html';                
}
```

**`order.html`**

```
function setData() {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        var quantity = getCookieValue("q"+i);

        if (quantity == null) {
            document.forms[0].elements["qty" + i].value = 0;
            document.forms[0].elements["cost" + i].value = 0.00;


        } else {
            document.forms[0].elements["qty" + i].value = quantity;
            var price = "q" + i;
    }
      calcTotal();

 }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting value = 1 each time.

```
document.cookie ="q" + value + "=1"; domain="/";
```

Try something like

```
document.cookie ="q1=" + value + "; domain="/";
```